# What programming language is best suited for a 2D platformer game with my experience?

Tags: 2d, game-engine, tiles

Me and a few friends want to start building a 2D puzzle platformer. It uses a lot of tiles and we experienced that our test level did not run smoothly with Java. Do any of you have suggestions on which programming language/engine would be best suited to make the game?

We have experience with Java and Actionscript 3.

Thank you in advance for your advise.

Comment: The language you and your friends feel most comfortable with for this problem is the one most suitable. If it isn't running smoothly, figure out why not.

Comment: I know this has an answer, but this is an opinion-based question and off-topic for SO. In the future, please try to avoid asking questions that require discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started with java and LibGdx as engine, it quite simple and has a good performance.

For further performance increase, you should maybe rethink the way of handling the tiles. Not rendering all tiles, create junks which are loaded, when the are used and unloaded when not.